# Facebook php SDK - simple datafetch

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to integrate my facebook app with PHP. What I need to do is have users go to the app-page, authenticate the app and then somehow I want to end up with a variable that contains the info I need so I can store it in MySQL.

I downloaded the facebook SDK, but I cannot figure out how to make it work. All the examples I can find refer to a file called facebook.php - but there is no such file in the SDK (maybe the changed it?).

I managed to get it working with JavaScript, but I don't know how to get from JavaScript to php (the user object, that is).

I would prefer to just run it entirely through php. What I'm trying to do is very simple, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The following, for instance, does not work:

```
<?php
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appid', 'appsecret');
require facebook-php-sdk-v4-master\src\Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php;

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  echo "error";
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  echo "error 2";
}
if ($session) {
    echo "logged in";
}

?>
```

Gives PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FacebookSession' not found in

Where do I go? I don't think the Facebook getting started guide is helpful at all. It just starts out with "you have to do this" (what I did above) - but that doesn't work?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Newest version... and Apache too.

Comment: 5.5.11 to be specific!

Comment: You need to require the FacebookSession.php file or configure an autoloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they changed the whole SDK for PHP 5.4.

Well there's a few options, you could go [with the older SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) and all those tutorials you found will work for that. Or you could learn some new things!

I suggest that if you want to use the new Facebook SDK, you go ahead an learn about [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) first, it makes including libraries a piece of cake and all you'd have to do is include the autoloader at the top of the file. Once done, you can just follow the [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) and it should work.

If you don't want to learn composer, you'll have to include all the required files manually. [Here's a basic example.](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/)

Comment: This gets me somewhere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But ... I can't figure out how to use php to fetch data AND javascript to login at the same time? I end up in a huge mess everytime.

I just need to login, get data, post to SQL. Why is this so hard? I coded an entire iOS app that does this by the push of a button and that seemed like a walk in the park compared to this.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it looks like the error was because you were calling

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication
```

Before you'd actually included the SDK